# Android 6.0 Permissions. Read SMS

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

I want to get the permission to read SMS in my App. This is my code:

```
String permission = Manifest.permission.READ_SMS;
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    permissionList.add(permission);

    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), permission)){
        requestPermissions(new String[]{permission}), SMS_PERMISSION);
    }
}
```

I didn't get dialog to confirm the permission request. For other permissions (like `WRITE_STORAGE`, `READ_CONTACTS`) I got this dialog. Do you know how to fix it?

Method `onRequestPermissionsResult` gives to me that permission isn't granted. But it works, without the confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need the `<uses-permission-sdk-23/>` for confirm dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the `read_sms` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` as well ?

Comment: yes, in my manifest file i've got a <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

Comment: Okey, i've found the trouble. I need **<uses-permission-sdk-23/>** for it. omg. For other permissions i dont need this. Thank you for andswer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int GET_MY_PERMISSION = 1;
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)){
            /* do nothing*/
        }
        else{

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},GET_MY_PERMISSION);
        }
    }
```

this piece of code works fine.
I used it on Nougat(api level:25) I hope it should work for you even!
I followed [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == ACCESS_SMS) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission granted"+checkboxChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("Checkedbox= "+checkboxChecked);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied"+checkboxChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```